# Specflow not working with Nunit 3.0 but working with NUnit 2.6

Tags: specflow

I am using specflow for BDD for a POC project. I had installed the nuget packages for Specflow ,Specflow.NUnit, NUnitTestAdapter and **NUnit (version 2.6)**. I seemed to be happy since i was getting the expected result.

After a few days, I am working on a new project and i installed all the nuget packages mentioned above. Everything worked fine again. However, **when i upgraded Nunit from version 2.6 to the latest stable version 3.0**, my **tests were not discovered in the Test explorer**. 
I can continue with the older version but still i would like to go with the latest stable version

I am not sure what steps do i need to take to get my specs running and see all my tests in the Test Explorer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of specflow at time of writing (1.9) won't work with nunit 3. The new version, currently under development (v2) will support it so you will need to wait for that to use nunit v3, or use the beta version from the CI build